# Testing equals method

Tags: java

I am having a weird issue which I am not being able to understand why this happens.

I have this `equals` method implemented in a `DoublyLinkedList` generic class:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass() || obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        DoublyLinkedList<E> other = (DoublyLinkedList<E>) obj;

        if (this.size != other.size) {
            return false;
        }

        Iterator<E> iterator = this.iterator();
        Iterator<E> otherIterator = other.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){       
            if(iterator.next() != otherIterator.next()){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Testing this method, in a unit test, like this:

```
@Test
public void testEquals() {
    System.out.println("equals");
    DoublyLinkedList <String> instance1 = new DoublyLinkedList <>(), instance2 = new DoublyLinkedList <>();

    instance1.addLast("Xpto");
    instance1.addLast("Ypto");
    instance1.addLast("Zpto");

    instance2.addLast("Xpto");
    assertFalse("Lists should not be equal", (instance1.equals(instance2)));
    assertFalse("Lists should not be equal", (instance2.equals(instance1)));        
    instance2.addLast("Ypto");
    assertFalse("Lists should not be equal", (instance1.equals(instance2)));
    assertFalse("Lists should not be equal", (instance2.equals(instance1)));
    instance2.addLast("Zpto");
    assertTrue("Lists should be equal", (instance1.equals(instance2)));
    assertTrue("Lists should be equal", (instance2.equals(instance1)));       
}
```

Gives me that the test passes. However, why does this happen, if I am using `!=`, instead of `equals` to compare each iterator's instance, in the first code? Shouldn't it compare the references, and thus fail?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are adding `String` literals to the list. The `String` class takes a shortcut and has two of the same Strings point to the same memory address so `==` and `!=` works

Comment: Read the last part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/8534008

Comment: String literals in Java are **interned**. This is defined in the JLS (Java Language Specification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is interning (or caching) certain references on your behalf.  Specifically, if you enter `String`s as your type, you're going to run into some curious String interning behavior, in that suddenly, your lists have the same reference of `String`.  This is the ***only*** way that `==` would work on a reference at all - if it were somehow interned or cached and could be referenced.

This is trivial to defeat; if you use values which do not have the ability to be interned or cached, then you'll observe that your test fails.

For example, `new BigInteger("100")` and `new BigInteger("100")` are not the same location in memory, and if you put both of those in your list and attempt to compare equivalence, you'll get `false`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because they are pointing to the same location in memory.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#d5e1634